# Extracting text from a string before the first occurrence of a symbol

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery, substring, text-extraction

I have data that looks like below-

```
type       A_URL                          B_URL             C_URL
A         123.com/123abc?....     123.com/123abc?....       123.com/123abc?....
B         pqr.com/435678?....     pqr.com/435678?....       pqr.com/435678?....
C         lmn.com/12u356?....     lmn.com/12u356?....       lmn.com/12u356?....
```

I want to create a new column URL and do the following-

if type is A extract everything that comes before the **first** '?' in A_URL column and store it to the new column url,

if type is B extract everything that comes before the **first** '?' in B_URL column and store it to the new column url,

if type is C extract everything that comes before the **first** '?' in C_URL column and store it to the new column url

The result should look like below-

```
type       A_URL                          B_URL             C_URL                     url
A         123.com/123abc?....     123.com/123abc?....       123.com/123abc?....     123.com/123abc?
B         pqr.com/435678?....     pqr.com/435678?....       pqr.com/435678?....     pqr.com/435678?
C         lmn.com/12u356?....     lmn.com/12u356?....       lmn.com/12u356?....     lmn.com/12u356?
```

Note: Although A_URL, B_URL and C_URL look the same above they have different information after the first "?" stored in each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_extract()`:

```
select t.*,
       regexp_extract(case when type = 'A' then a_url
                           when type = 'B' then b_url
                           when type = 'C' then c_url
                      end,
                      '^[^?]+'

from t;
```

EDIT:

If you want to keep the final `?`, then use:

```
select t.*,
       regexp_extract(case when type = 'A' then a_url
                           when type = 'B' then b_url
                           when type = 'C' then c_url
                      end,
                      '^[^?]+[?]'

from t;
```

Comment: @Gordon_Linoff Thanks! What if I want to include the '?' as well in the final url column?

Comment: You would use `'^[^?]+[?]'`.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(url),
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, r'^[^?]+\?') AS url
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST([CASE type 
  WHEN 'A' THEN A_URL 
  WHEN 'B' THEN B_URL 
  WHEN 'C' THEN C_URL 
END]) url
```